# MySQL - update values in table returned from query?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I fired this query where I join two tables and output some of the columns of both tables:

```
SELECT B.option_id, B.product_id, A.title, B.identifier 
FROM `catalog_product_option_title` A JOIN
     `catalog_product_option` B
     ON A.option_id = B.option_id
WHERE A.title = "Breite"
```

Result:

[image]

Now I need to enter the example value `xyz` on the column `identifier` in the result, everywhere. I would go ahead and do this by hand.

How can I make use of the `update` statement from MySQL to solve this without having to manually change it by hand?

I tried it like this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option`
SET identifier = 'xyz'
WHERE option_id IN (
    SELECT A.option_id 
    FROM `catalog_product_option_title` A 
    JOIN
         `catalog_product_option` B
         ON A.option_id = B.option_id
    WHERE A.title = "Breite"
)
```

But the simulation of this query returned that this would change 0 lines.

**UPDATE**

I called the sql without simulating it, and now I get this error:

> ## 1093 - Table 'catalog_product_option' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your query as a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option` B
JOIN `catalog_product_option_title` A ON A.option_id = B.option_id
SET B.identifier = 'xyz' WHERE A.title = "Breite"
```

Comment: Wow, I was not aware that we can use JOIN in UPDATE, thx man!

Comment: @Black yeah it's pretty cool. There's a bit of info about it in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) but it's not as well documented as it could be. It should also be a lot more efficient than a nested subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this please?

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_option`
SET identifier = 'xyz'
WHERE option_id IN (
    SELECT option_id FROM (SELECT A.option_id 
    FROM `catalog_product_option_title` A 
    JOIN
         `catalog_product_option` B
         ON A.option_id = B.option_id
    WHERE A.title = "Breite") as x
)
```